# How to set vertical height in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I need to give vertical height for the right element with full background. I tried by setting

> height:100%; 
>   max-height: 100%

but the element takes only content height

```css
.full_container {
     height: 350px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .pull-left {
     float: left;
    }
    .width50 {
     width: 50%;
    }
    .inline_height {
     color: #fff;
        padding: 10px;
     background: #333;
    }
    .height100 {
     padding: 10px;
     height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        background: #e8e8e8;
    }
```

```html
<div class="full_container">
 <div class="clearfix">
     <div class="pull-left width50">
         <div class="inline_height">
             Content height only
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left width50">
         <div class="height100">
             <div>I need to show this div element height to 100%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the `.clearfix` class a `display:flex` and `height:100%`

```
.clearfix {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Example below

```css
.full_container {
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.width50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.inline_height {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.height100 {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}

.clearfix {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full_container">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left width50">
      <div class="inline_height">
        Content height only
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left width50">
      <div class="height100">
        <div>I need to show this div element height to 100%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this:
 I have added `display: flex` for `.full_container`

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.full_container {
  height: 350px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: flex;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

.width50 {
  width: 50%;
}

.inline_height {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #333;
}

.height100 {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="full_container">
    <div class="pull-left width50">
      <div class="inline_height">
        Content height only
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pull-left width50">
      <div class="height100">
        <div>I need to show this div element height to 100%</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```